# Do ARM processors/OS for ARM - have security rings?

Tags: x86, operating-system, arm, privileges, processor

I wonder, do ARM processors have special registers to support the idea of security rings and do operating systems such as Android, Palm or others support security rings?

In Wiki, there is some info that ARM processors don't have such registers as x86 for supporting such type of work.

But, I think that register is just the place with fixed size, where you can put and take info?
So, the concept/idea of security rings is on OS only or x86-processors really have special registers for these aims, but on ARM-only OS is supporting this mode?

Am I right or not?

I have googled and wikied this topic, but there only few information, which isn't full.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no security rings. But there are different processor modes:
http://www.heyrick.co.uk/assembler/regs.html , http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Chdddhea.html

In short - most used are System and User. All userspace programs works in User mode. Kernel works in System mode.

Answer (score 13):

All platforms that are intended to support operating systems with memory isolation do have some kind of privilege system. On x86 processors, the privilege levels are called “ring 0” through “ring 3”. On ARM processors, the privilege levels are called “supervisor mode” and “user mode”. The names and implementations are different, but the concepts are the same. Some registers are banked, i.e. there is a separate register in different mode; other registers are shared, so the more privileged mode must take care to validate the value on input and not to leak data on output.

Recent x86 processors, and recent ARM processors, have additional sets of register to handle virtualization.

Comment: For the record, modern x86 OSes don't use ring 1 or ring 2.  Ring 0 is equivalent to "supervisor" / "kernel" mode on ARM / MIPS / most other ISAs.  Ring 3 is equivalent to "user" mode on other ISAs.  Intel [recently proposed](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/envisioning-future-simplified-architecture.html) a "simplified" x86S ISA that fully drops 16-bit mode, and drops ring 1 and ring 2, so it would work like other modern ISAs, and boot in 64-bit long mode.  (It keeps 32-bit *compat* mode for 32-bit user-space under a 64-bit kernel.)